# Why does Spring boot Kafka client app runs with maven but not with java -jar

Tags: maven, apache-kafka

I have a Spring boot (2.7.2) Kafka client app that reads Kafka topic and updates database tables, it works if I start it from Intellij or using the command:
`./mvnw spring-boot:run -Dspring.profiles.active=prod`

but it does not work using java -jar and throws an exception
`java -jar target/VidKafka-v1.war -Dspring.profiles.active=prod`
OR
`java -jar target/VidKafka-v1.war -Dspring.profiles.active=prod -Dhttp.proxyHost=quad3proxy.aa.com -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080 -Dhttps.proxyHost=quad3proxy.aa.com -Dhttps.proxyPort=8080 -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts="localhost|*.aa.com|*.gmsupplypower.com" -Djava.security.krb5.conf=WEB-INF/classes/Krb5-prod.conf -Djava.security.auth.login.config=WEB-INF/classes/JAAS-prod-with-keytab.conf`

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'org.springframework.kafka.config.internalKafkaListenerEndpointRegistry'; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka consumer
```

Please advise.

it starts fine if I start it inside Intellij or using maven ./mvnw command

Comment: I have all my conf files externalized, and when I try to start with java -jar I get these 3 exceptions, and the app does not login to Kafka.  However it works with ./mvnw startup & logs into Kafka ----

Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka consumer

Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jasypt/encryption/pbe/config/PBEConfig

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jasypt/encryption/pbe/config/PBEConfig

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.config.PBEConfig

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue by adding this dependency, now the app starts with java -jar

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jasypt/jasypt -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jasypt</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasypt</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.3</version>
</dependency>
```